# For loop not working as intended

Tags: python

I am in the middle of my course work and I am now having trouble with one of my for loops.

```
def update():
update=[]
update1=[]
with open('Stock2.txt','r') as stockFile:
    for eachLine in stockFile:
        eachLine=eachLine.strip().split()
        update.append(eachLine)
    update.remove(update[0])
stockFile.close()
with open('Stock2.txt','r') as stockFile:
    for eachLine in stockFile:
        eachLine=eachLine.strip().split(' ')
        update1.append(eachLine)
    update1.remove(update1[0])
for eachList in update1:
    loopCon=-1
    for eachItem in eachList:
        loopCon+=1
        if eachItem=='':
            eachList[loopCon]=' '

count=-1
for eachList in update1:
    for eachItem in eachList:
        count+=1
        if eachItem != ' ':
            print(count)
```

The last for loop that I have been working on is looping ok but when I add one to count every time it loops on the for loop 'for eachItem in eachList:' it comes up with random numbers as follows:

0 10 14 21 28 35 36 46 62 69 76 83 84 94 111
Here is the stock file I am using - Stock2.txt

```
GTIN-8            Product-Name        Price(£)     CSL     ROL     TSL
95820194          Windows-10-64bit    119.99       0       1       3
68196167          Cheese                1.00       0       3       8
62017014          Bread                 0.93       0       3       9
86179616          10tb-memory-stick   916.96       0       0       4
19610577          Freddo                0.15       0       2       9
```

So on.
Is there anything I have done wrong whilst doing this as I probably would not be able to detect it that easily as I have only been doing python for almost 1 year.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: when you use `with open` you shouldn't need to close the file afterwards.

Comment: You're only printing count when a condition is passed

Comment: You mention that the output is `0 10 14 21 ...`. What output do you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks for that Moses Koledoye.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `count` outside the `if` that prints. Try this instead:

```
for eachList in update1:
    for eachItem in eachList:
        if eachItem != ' ':
            count+=1
            print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put a `print update1` statement before your last `for` loop, i.e., before the statement `for eachList in update1:`, I get the following output:

`[['95820194', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Windows-10-64bit', ' ', ' ', ' ', '119.99', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3'], ['68196167', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Cheese', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1.00', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8'], ['62017014', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Bread', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0.93', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9'], ['86179616', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '10tb-memory-stick', ' ', ' ', '916.96', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '4'], ['19610577', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Freddo', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0.15', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9']]`

So by this it seems the output isnt random at all. What you are doing is traversing each list inside the list `update1`, and you are incrementing `count` each time you get an element in `eachItem`.

However you are printing `count` only when `eachItem != ' '`. So as you can see it prints `0` when `eachItem == '95820194'`, and then it prints `10` when `eachItem == 'Windows-10-64bit'`, and so on. Though it is incremented even when `eachItem == ' '`, just not printed.